# Element or attribute do not match QName production: QName::=(NCName':')?NCName

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to learn XML and validation.

Here is my code XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Datum>2001-02-28</Datum>
```

Here is my Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:element name:"Datum" type:"xsd:date"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

I am trying to validate this via xmlvalidation.com and it gives me the error:

```
Element or attribute do not match QName production: QName::=(NCName':')?NCName.
```

Also how do I define in my Schema that the date should be absolut? If it is something is than this date, it should return an error.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected the error in the scheme.

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:element name="Datum" type="xsd:date"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Thank you!! It verified now.